# Service Fabric Powershell from Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, continuous-integration, azure-service-fabric

I am able to successfully deploy Service Fabric services to my local cluster from Azure Devops using the ServiceFabricDeploy task with a configured service connection. What I need is the ability to run some arbitrary powershell scripts against the fabric in order to perform other maintenance tasks that I want to automate via CI/CD.

How can I get a normal inline powershell task connected to my local fabric so I can interact with the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SF PowerShell module for that.
First [connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/connect-servicefabriccluster?view=azureservicefabricps) to the cluster.
Next, manage the cluster using the provided functions.

Under water, these commands use the REST API of SF. Therefore you can't just run arbitrary code.
If you want to do that, you'll need to use SSH or something like PowerShell [remoting](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/powershell-basics-connecting-to-vms-with-azure-psremoting/ba-p/428403).

More info on how to set it up in the Load Balancer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-remote-connect-to-azure-cluster-node).